# OpenSSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number (Jenkins)

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, openssl, ssl-certificate

Run jenkins 2.414.1 with ssl and get the following error.

Also Added JAVA_ARGS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2" in /etc/default/jenkins and restart server. Still get the same error.

wget https://localhost

--2023-08-30 17:19:52--  https://localhost/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
Unable to establish SSL connection.

lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

jenkins --version

2.414.1

openssl version

OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

Comment: `https.protocols` only affects the version(s) used for _outgoing_ connections that already specify HTTPS, and even then only if they use certain libraries. It has no relationship to or affect of any kind on _incoming_ connections. Whatever you did to "run jenkins with ssl" appears to be wrong, but since we have no clue what you did, no one can know or say what the problem is.